# Deleting element from an observableArray

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js, entity-framework-5, breeze

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses durandal, knockout.js, and breeze on the client.  I have an issue that I'm encountering repeatedly, and yet I haven't found any mention of it anywhere.  Not sure if I've gotten myself into a unique situation, or if I'm just not searching the right way.

I need to know how to delete a Breeze entity from an observableArray so that the commit succeeds (see Option A below) and the UI reflects the change (see Option B below).

I have the following models (abbreviated):

```
public class Donor
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Donor")]
    public int? DonorId { get; set; }
    public virutal Donor Donor { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to delete a Contact from my Donor.  I am having difficulty getting the flow right between Breeze and Knockout so that the item is both removed from the `observableArray` (with a notification) and also able to be deleted through Breeze.

Here is what I have tried (javascript):

**Option A**:

```
function deleteContact(contact){
    viewModel.donor().contacts.remove(contact);
    contact.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    viewModel.uow.commit();
}
```

When I use this approach, I get the following error from Breeze.WebApi:

> Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Int64

I have looked through the stack, and examined the Breeze source code (though I haven't yet configured a solution to step through it), and the error is coming from Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider::RestoreOriginal, where it is restoring original property values to the object.  I don't know why it thinks my value is an Int64, but I was not able to find a good work-around, so I tried...

**Option B**:

```
function deleteContact(contact){
    contact.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    viewModel.uow.commit();
}
```

This approach allows me to successfully save the delete (because the item has not been removed from the collection manually, and therefore, doesn't have any "original values").  However, the issue here is that `setDeleted` effectively removes the item from the observableArray **without notifying** my knockout bindings that the array has changed.  So the item has been removed and deleted, but my UI still shows the item.  Future attempts to call `donor().contacts.remove(contact)` are futile, because the observableArray no longer has the item.

Comment: Have you tried calling `valueHasMutated()` on your observable array after using option b?

Comment: I had not tried that, and it does work, so thank you.  Go ahead and add an answer - I'm curious if any of the IdeaBlade people have thoughts about this, so I may leave it open a day or two to see if they chime in.  Still wondering if I'm the only one who's getting that converter error...

Comment: Is Breeze supposed to be KO aware? Consider: `var foo = ko.observableArray(["A"]); foo.push("B");` This updates the array and DOM.  `foo().push("C");` This only updates the array. Option A does it right, but Option B, from your experience, doesn't. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Jaq/) example. You can see the values were unshifted to each array, but only one updated  the DOM. If you add `vm.foo.valueHasMutated();` after applyBindings, then the DOM updates both, which is the simplified version of what's happening here and why that works.

Comment: @Dennis - yes, I believe Breeze is KO-aware.  When I use Breeze to retrieve my entities, Breeze KO-izes everything behind the scenes, meaning all properties on my entity are either observables or observableArrays.  So it is clearly recognizing that KO is involved, and making my objects KO-friendly.  [This topic](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/databinding-knockout) in the Breeze documentation talks specifically to this integration.

Comment: I'll have to read up on Breeze, but I can't imagine they have you calling valueHasMutated explicitly in tutorials after committing changes to an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling `valueHasMutated()` on your observable array after using option b?

This will notify subscribers that the observable has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'delete' or 'detach' an entity Breeze should remove that entity from any navigation collections automatically. So I would try eliminating the

```
 viewModel.donor().contacts.remove(contact);
```

line and see if calling 'setDeleted' by itself does what you need.

Comment: Take a look at my option B above, which does not include the explicit removal of the entity, and you'll see why this doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your post more carefully. I'll run some tests to confirm this.  If you are right, then I'll add this to be fixed in one of the next releases. Until then, calling valueHasMutated directly should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

### TL:DR

Never set the FKs in the initializer of createEntity while also pushing the entity to the parent's navigation property. Keeps to either one of them, but not both.

### Underlying principles

After having encountered a similar issue and done much investigations, I would like to propose an alternate answer. The issue you are experimenting is not about how you delete the item but how you **create** the item.

Breeze is very able when it comes to managing its data context. It knows about navigation properties and foreign keys and how to handle them. As a side effect of the local data context, all observables also posses this intelligence. This is where you probably overlooked something and ended up with this issue.

### Tracing breeze's code

What does this all means concretely? Well, there is two ways that you can use to create an object with a parent entity using breeze. The first one is by setting its parent id in the initializer, like so:

```
var c = manager.createEntity('contact', { 'donorId': 12, 'name': 'bob' });
```

The other is by adding the entity to the navigation property on the parent's entity in the breeze data context.

```
var parents = ko.observableArray();
manager.runQuery(..., parents);

var c = manager.createEntity('contact', { 'name': 'bob'});
parents.contacts.push(c);
```

Both cases have their pros and cons. The problem arises when you try to do both:

```
var parents = ko.observableArray();
manager.runQuery(..., parents);

var c = manager.createEntity('contact', { 'donorId': 12, 'name': 'bob' });
parents.contacts.push(c);
```

Breeze tries to optimize its queries when dealing with insertions to prevent UI flickering. When calling `push`, it disables notifications on the target observable until the entire operation is done. Then, it will call `valueHasMutated` internally which will trigger a UI refresh. The thing is, calling `createEntity` interfere with this mechanism and causes the notification to be reinitialized too soon. The `push` will then save this invalid sate, swap it and reset it, leaving the observable in an invalid state.

When you ultimately call `setDeleted` the notifications will still be disabled on the observable preventing a UI refresh even though the data is properly pushed in breeze's data context. This will only happen once after inserting a new element. Deleting an element will force the state to be changed to its proper value and all subsequent deletion on the navigation property will trigger a UI refresh.

### Looking at your two options

In the end, you only have to use `setDeleted` to properly remove an entity from a breeze navigation property. There is no need to remove it from the observable manually and, in fact, doing this will reset the foreign key to `null` which might cause deserialization issues on the server if the type is not nullable in your model or errors when trying to delete the row from the database depending on how your primary key is defined. Option B is the one to go with.